# Caching css to update the style in facebook

Tags: php, facebook

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'` error points to "after .css" :

```
echo '<fb:recommendations bordercolor="'.$bordercolor.'" colorscheme="'.$colorscheme.'" recommendations="'.$recommTxt.'" height="'.$height.'" width="'.$width.'" header="'.$header.'" site="'.$site.' " css="'.'"<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>/style.css?2"></fb:recommendations>';
```

I am trying to make some style changes to fb recommendation box, so the full path of css file is not feasible since the files will move to different server with different domain..

I might have overlooked single or double quotes? I am bad with these..

Could you please point / guide me to correct that? thank you

**EDIT #2**

```
css="'.'"<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>/style.css?2"
```

it was updated but on firebug I see:

```
<fb:recommendations class=" fb_iframe_widget " clear"="" css="http://xxx.com/wp-content/themes/xxx/facebook.css?2></fb:recommendations></div> </div><!--/sidebar--> <div class=" site="xxx.com " header="false" width="245" height="" recommendations="true" colorscheme="White" bordercolor="#fdbc88">
```

it is strange to see .

Comment: "I might have overlooked single or double quotes? I am bad with these.." --- if you are - then do your work **ITERATIVELY**, by small steps. Make one **SMALL** change at a time and **CHECK** if it works as expected. In this case you would know for sure what caused a error. So my advice is to roll back to the original **worked** code and apply changes one by one, with continuous checking if everything goes smoothly

Comment: @zerkms - thanks for the quick comment, and i have done that - but just I thought that I got it right and checking the source view shows that the code isn't right.

Comment: @Josephine: if you have done that you should know what exactly caused a error. So which part of that long line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
css="'. bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ) . '/style.css?2"
```

As long as it is already a php code - you shouldn't specify `<?php`